# Is there any performance reason to use powers of two for field sizes in my database?

Tags: sql, database, optimization

A long time ago when I was a young lat I used to do a lot of assembler and optimization programming. Today I mainly find myself building web apps (it's alright too...). However, whenever I create fields for database tables I find myself using values like 16, 32 & 128 for text fields and I try to combine boolean values into SET data fields.

Is giving a text field a length of 9 going to make my database slower in the long run and do I actually help it by specifying a field length that is more easy memory aligned?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212380/should-database-variable-length-text-fields-be-powers-of-2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Database optimization is quite unlike machine code optimization. With databases, most of the time you want to reduce disk I/O, and wastefully trying to align fields will only make less records fit in a disk block/page. Also, if any alignment is beneficial, the database engine will do it for you automatically.

What will matter most is indexes and how well you use them. Trying tricks to pack more information in less space can easily end up making it harder to have good indexes. (Do not overdo it, however; not only do indexes slow down INSERTs and UPDATEs to indexed columns, they also mean more work for the planner, which has to consider all the possibilities.)

Most databases have an EXPLAIN command; try using it on your selects (in particular, the ones with more than one table) to get a feel for how the database engine will do its work.

Answer (score 1):

The size of the field itself may be important, but usually for text if you use nvarchar or varchar it is not a big deal. Since the DB will take what you use. the follwoing will have a greater impact on your SQL speed:

don't have more columns then you need. bigger table in terms of columns means the database will be less likely to find the results for your queries on the same disk page. Notice that this is true even if you only ask for 2 out of 10 columns in your select... (there is one way to battle this, with clustered indexes but that can only address one limited scenario).

you should give more details on the type of design issues/alternatives you are considering to get additional tips.

Comment: So that means that combining boolean values into a single column using a SET type (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html) is a good idea...

Answer (score 0):

Something that is implied above, but which can stand being made explicit. You don't have any way of knowing what the computer is actually doing. It's not like the old days when you could look at the assembler and know pretty well what steps the program is going to take. A value that "looks" like it's in a CPU register may actually have to be fetched from a cache on the chip or even from the disk. If you are not writing assembler but using an optimizing compiler, or even more surely, bytecode on a runtime engine (Java, C#), abandon hope. Or abandon worry, which is the better idea.

It's probably going to take thousands, maybe tens of thousands of machine cycles to write or retrieve that DB value. Don't worry about the 10 additional cycles due to full word alignments.